# Group contiguous ranges of dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with this data (CurrentDay  Availability Price MinStay IdRate):

```
2014-12-01  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-02  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-03  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-04  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-05  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-06  2   124.00  0   123456
2014-12-07  2   124.00  0   123456
2014-12-08  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-09  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-10  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-11  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-12  0   0.00    0   123456
2014-12-13  0   0.00    0   123456
```

It is possible create a query (no store procedure) that retrive a result like this?

```
2014-12-01 2014-12-05 0 0.00    0   123456
2014-12-06 2014-12-07 2 124.00  0   123456
2014-12-08 2014-12-13 0 0.00    0   123456
```

I tried this but it is wrong

```
SELECT Min([CurrentDay])
      ,Max([CurrentDay])
      ,[Availability]
      ,[Price]
      ,[MinStay]
      ,[IdRate]
  FROM [ChannelBooking].[dbo].[Inventory]
  GROUP BY Price, MinStay, [IdRate], [Availability]
```

The database is SQL Server 2008, actually I do this by software.

Comment: I need the start date and the end date, the query is ok but result is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok maybe I found solution:

```
 WITH    q AS
            (
            SELECT  [Availability], [Price],CurrentDay,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Availability], [Price] ORDER BY CurrentDay) AS rnd,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Availability] ORDER BY CurrentDay) AS rn,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CurrentDay) AS colID
            FROM    [Inventory]

            WHERE (CurrentDay >= '12-01-2014' and CurrentDay <= '12-31-2014')

            )
    SELECT  MIN(CurrentDay), MAX(CurrentDay), [Availability], [Price]
    FROM    q
    GROUP BY  [Availability], [Price], rnd - rn, rnd - colID
    ORDER BY      MIN(CurrentDay)
```